# custom action bar keeps disappearing when i switch between fragments using the navDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I wanted to add my own custom action bar to the drawer navigation by Google which i have figured out, the problem is, that when I try to open the drawer the Action bar then disappears, along with the icon that allows me to toggle the drawer is also gone for good. it again disappears when i click on my next fragment activity. I also noticed that if i leave the theme of the app back to its default theme everything works fine.

here's my custom theme style class

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#f0f0</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

When it works i use @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar for the theme

Comment: Scratch that problem was in my styles class had to use the "@android:style/Theme" first and then the "@android:style/Widget" for my custom theme